# Docker-compose not reading logging config in /etc/docker/daemon.json

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've got a `daemon.json` file, stored in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. to configure the docker daemon with following contents:

```
{
  "log-driver" : "syslog",
  "log-opts": {
     "syslog-facility": "local1",
     "tag": "{{.Name}}"
  },
  "storage-driver": "devicemapper",
  "storage-opts": [
     "dm.fs=xfs",
     "dm.thinpooldev=/dev/mapper/vg00-docker--pool",
     "dm.use_deferred_removal=true"
  ]
}
```

None of the docker-compose services have logging options configured, nor are any of the docker containers configured to start with `--log-driver` in their `cmd` or `entrypoint`.

Inspecting the output of the `docker info` command, I can verify that the logging driver is set to `syslog`.

However when running a docker-compose stack, all of the containers still show `json-file` upon inspecting them with the command `docker inspect --format='{{.HostConfig.LogConfig.Type}}'` , which seems to me as if `docker-compose` is not respecting the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` config file, just for the logging config, as the `storage-driver` is set correctly.

The docker version I used to run this is `17.12.0`, docker-compose is at `1.19.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/docker/daemon.json` is default config file and docker daemon should access if exists when starts. Maybe there's something wrong in your file according to the configuration (because it looks ok according to syntax).

**Let's try to force config-file read with debug enabled and see which error it shows.**

```
/usr/bin/dockerd stop
/usr/bin/dockerd start -D -l debug --config-file /etc/docker/daemon.json
```

After that, you can see logs with `journalctl -u docker`

Alternatively, you know that you can test easily each config param passing them one by one via cli instead json config file, in order to figure out which of them causes that configuration is not load.

```
/usr/bin/dockerd stop
/usr/bin/dockerd start -D -l debug --log-driver syslog --storage-driver devicemapper ...
```

Adding one by one you will be able to check if for example it fails with storage-opts because /dev/mapper/vg00-docker--pool is not mounted or whatever.